# MySQL Update table from 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, inner-join

Could somebody please help me write a MySQL query to update some data I need to recreate from a corrupted source.  Due to a programming error I’ve had to delete about 9000 row of corrupt data.  I have a copy of the good data but can’t work out the joins to get the good data back into the repaired table.

I have 2 tables from a school with the following relevant columns

```
Table A – tbl_Lessons
Lesson_id
Lesson_class_id
Lesson_date
Lesson_term

Table B – tbl_Register
Register_id
Register_lesson_id
Register_student_id
Register_status
Register_update_by
Register_update_dat
```

So for each class_id there is a unique lesson_id for each date it is taught.
And for each lesson_id there is a unique register entry for each student taught.
All lessons from the current term had to be recreated and so the register for all lessons also had to be recreated.

```
Table C – Backup Data before deletion.
(Create table tbl_tmp_register  as
select * from tbl_register inner join tbl_lessons on lesson_id = register_lesson_id
where lesson_term = "autumn 2019")

Lesson_id
Lesson_class_id
Lesson_date
Lesson_term
Register_id
Register_lesson_id
Register_student_id
Register_status
Register_update_by
Register_update_date
```

So what I would like to do is update Table B (register_status, register_update_by, register_update_date)  with the data from the backup table.    I know what it should be by looking in the backup table for the row that matches lesson_class_id , lesson_date & register_student_id but I cannot write the SQL to get the data copied across.   I have tried and failed many times.  I think this is quite close to update one field but it just seems to hang the server even if I narrow the register down to one class on one day.

```
update tbl_register as r inner join tbl_lessons as l on r.register_lesson_id = l.lesson_id,
    (select register_student_status from tbl_tmp_register as TTR inner join tbl_lessons as L on L.lesson_class_id = TTR.lesson_class_id AND l.lesson_Date = TTR.Lesson_date) as tt
Set r.register_student_status = tt.register_student_status
where l.lesson_class_id = 000 and l.lesson_date = '2019-xx-yy';
```

If I try it another way with a more straight forward query I also hang the server.

```
update tbl_register as dest
inner join tbl_tmp_register as srce
on srce.register_student_id = dest.register_student_id 
inner join tbl_lessons as otsrce
on otsrce.lesson_class_id = srce.lesson_class_id and otsrce.lesson_date = srce.lesson_date
set dest.register_student_status = srce.register_student_status
```

I know I'm close but not quite getting the joins right.
Any help much appreciated.

**Edit with Sample data for NBK:**
In the backup data set the register_id and the lesson_id are not identical to the new data set in the register and lesson tables as these have been regenerated so the link between the old and new is the student id, class id, and class date.

```
Sample data

Table A – lessons
Lesson_id:1
Lesson_class_id: 22
Lesson_date: 2019-09-01
Lesson_term: Autumn 2019

Table B- registers
Register_id:1
Register_lesson_id:1
Register_student_id:33
Register_status: NULL
Register_update_by: NULL
Register_update_dat: NULL

Register_id:2
Register_lesson_id:1
Register_student_id:44
Register_status: NULL
Register_update_by: NULL
Register_update_dat: NULL
…

Table C- Backup
Lesson_id: 555
Lesson_class_id: 1
Lesson_date: 2019-09-01
Lesson_term: Autumn 2019
Register_id: 666
Register_lesson_id: 1
Register_student_id: 33
Register_status: Present
Register_update_by: TeacherX
Register_update_date: 2019-09-02

Lesson_id: 556
Lesson_class_id: 1
Lesson_date: 2019-09-01
Lesson_term: Autumn 2019
Register_id: 667
Register_lesson_id: 1
Register_student_id: 44
Register_status: Late
Register_update_by: TeacherX
Register_update_date: 2019-09-02
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data. It is hard to imagine, that after joining tbl_register  and tbl_tmp_register  another join would give you other data for your set.

Comment: I've edited the question and put some sample data in for NBK.

Comment: thanks, but could you put data in https://dbfiddle.uk and post the link(also test your update there

Comment: Thanks @nbk Quite a useful excerise putting it in dbfiddle (which I've not used before) as it allowed me to see the data in a much smaller chunk but still struggling to get the joins right.  [link]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=37ad938ff138384a4012c1205cb310b7